# Genymotion unable to start VirtualBox (ubuntu 16.10)

Tags: virtualbox, 16.10, genymotion

I'm trying to install Genymotion on ubuntu 16.10 here is what I did:

```
wget https://dl.genymotion.com/releases/genymotion-2.8.1/genymotion-2.8.1_x64.bin
sudo chmod +x genymotion-2.8.1_x64.bin
sudo ./genymotion-2.8.1_x64.bin
```

Then I installed VirtualBox

```
sudo apt install virtualbox
```

Then I tried to lunch Genymotion

```
cd /opt/genymobile/genymotion/
./genymotion
```

[image]

I also tried with sudo

```
sudo ./genymotion
```

but no difference

Comment: I have Genymotion working on 14.04. I did not use the VirtualBox package from the repository, but used the installer on https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads because I wanted the latest version. You could try that. Also, the error in the image says there is a log file. It would probably be helpful to see the contents of that log file.

Comment: Well you're lucky. I just get `./genymotion: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: FcWeightFromOpenType`. Straight upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10 btw.

Edit1: Apparently, I got it working by adding `sudo`. Also, protip: For ease of access, try `sudo ln -s /opt/genymobile/genymotion/genymotion /usr/bin/genymotion`

Comment: Same issue, nothing found

Answer (score 1):

Got and solved the same problem on Ubuntu 17.10:

1. Install the [latest version](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) of VirtualBox for your Ubuntu release
2. Fix the "missing headers" error:

   > $ sudo apt install virtualbox-5.2
   >   [...]
   >   This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
   >   Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
   >   for adding new hardware support to the system.
   >   The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
   >
   > ```
   >     linux-headers-lowlatency linux-headers-4.13.0-16-lowlatency
   > ```
   >
   > There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
   >   /sbin/vboxconfig
   >   as root.

   by installing the missing headers:

   ```
   sudo apt install linux-headers-lowlatency linux-headers-4.13.0-16-lowlatency
   ```
3. Rerun the setup process by running:

   ```
   sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
   ```

Answer (score 1):

First Unistall Previous Version Of virtual Box. Then follow two steps below

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
```

Then start genymotion again. It should work

Answer (score 1):

I did the following steps to resolve that issue.

1. Restart the machine and logged into the BIOS settings (Press F1 while rebooting the machine).
2. Under the “Security” tab “Disabled” the “Secure Boot”.

Hope this will help.